# Java, can't find average of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program that finds an average of all values in the array and then returns ones larger than the average.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class AboveAverage {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count=0, num;
        int nums[] = new int[1000];
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        System.out.println("Input +ve integers, to stop type 0");
        num = kbd.nextInt();
        while( num > 0 ) {
            nums[count] = num;
            count = count + 1;
            num = kbd.nextInt();
        }

        int d = 0;
        while ( d < 1000 ) {
            sum += nums[d];
            d++;
            average = sum / nums[d];
        }

        for(int i=0; i < count ; i=i+1) {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

In my opinion problem is in this line
I tried the one below which gives an exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at AboveAvarage.main(AboveAvarage.java:23)

```
 average = sum / nums[d];
```

I also tried

```
 average = sum / nums.length;
```

Which gave me the sum instead of the average.

Comment: Divide by `count`, and stop your `d` `while` loop if `d` reaches `count`.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `average` inside your `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the other *while* loop, add up sum upon input. When done, just divide by count

```
while( num > 0 ) {
  nums[count] = num;
  count = count + 1;
  sum += num;
  num = kbd.nextInt();
 }

average = sum / count;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that array indices in Java go from zero? This means the allowed indices in your `nums` array are `0` through `999`.

Now look at this loop:

```
int d = 0;
while ( d < 1000 ) {
sum += nums[d];
d++;
average = sum / nums[d];
}
```

- First, it adds the current number to the sum. This is correct.
- Then, it increments the number.
- Then it uses the incremented number to access `nums[d]` to calculate the average.

Now, imagine that you are at the last round. `d` is `999`.

- First, it adds the current number to the sum.
- Then it increments d. Now it is 1000.
- Then it uses the incremented number to access `nums[d]`. But this means `nums[1000]`. And that's an illegal index.

So this explains why you have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should never use the index again after you incremented it, because the `while` only guaranteed that its *previous* value was less than 1000. If you change the value, you need to test again. This is why normally the increment step is the last in the loop.

As for your logic:

To calculate an average, you first need to know the sum. After you know the sum, you can divide by the number of items you are averaging. So you need to divide the sum by the number of items you read.

So:

- You should *not* do a loop up to 1000. If you entered 0 after 5 numbers when you inputted the data, then there will be no values in the rest of the array (or rather, there will be zeros there).
- You can calculate the sum, as another answer told you, in the first loop. No need to do that in the second loop.
- You don't calculate the sum and the average in the same step. You first have to complete calculating the sum (finish the loop, be it the first or the second), and only then you can divide by the number of items (which you saved in `count`).
- Then you have to go through another loop, that prints the numbers that are larger than the average. Your print loop prints *all* the numbers. You should check each number, see if it is greater than the average you calculated, and only if it is, print it.

**Hint**: there should really only be two loops: One that reads the numbers and calculates the `count` and the `sum`. Then you calculate the average, but that's not a repeating action, so it should *not* be in a loop. The second loop is for printing the numbers that are above average.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop that is gathering values, you are using `count` to track how many values are provided.

In the subsequent loop to calculate the average, you should only look at `count` items of the array:

```
int d = 0;
while(d<count) {
    sum += nums[d];
}
average = sum/count;
```

Note you don't need to calculate `average` within the loop - do it once you've summed the values.